# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method after Parse implementation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've read everywhere - couldn't find a solution.

My project was working fine, I stated the methods I wanted to be called to the onClick inside the XML file like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:id="@+id/actualMainActivity"
tools:context=".ActualMainActivity"
><Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add new noob"
    android:id="@+id/addNewNoob"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:onClick="addNewNoob"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/listOfNoobs"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

the method inside my java class (ActualMainActivity) was like this:

```
  public void addNewNoob(View view) {
    Log.i("Tag", "you clicked the add button");
}
```

Only after I've implemented the Parse SDK to work with, my Gradle resynced and now when I run the application I get the 'Method not found exception'.
I would like to point out that when I assign an onClickListener directly to the button like this: 
    final Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addNewNoob);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Tag", "you clicked the add button");
            }
        });

that works perfectly fine...

What have I changed when I installed the SDK ? 
How can I get back to the way that I write the methods on XML and they are executed accordingly.

Really confused... thanks in advance

here's the logcat:

```
02-09 11:29:34.917    2669-2669/com.example.shaked.sqliteexample02 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shaked.sqliteexample02, PID: 2669
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method listOfNoobs(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'listOfNoobs'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3994)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: listOfNoobs [class android.view.View]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3987)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you clean the project?

Comment: and what is this listOfNoobs method? did you created and deleted that method?

Comment: listOfNoobs is just another method in my code I removed from the XML for the sake of the debugging... On a completely new activity I can use methods the "XML way"

Comment: i think its just a cache issue. clean the project and run!

Comment: What do I need to look at when I'm cleaning my project ?

Comment: in Android Studio you could find it under Build -> clean project.

Comment: Did it, problem persists... is there anything else related to the specific activity I should be looking at which maybe was also altered ?

Comment: check the layout whether you have missed to remove a onclick pointing listOfNoobs .

Comment: is it fixed @shaqed?

Comment: No, I'm really confused... the methods are there - I have changed nothing in my code except installing that SDK which after I removed and now I this problem persists...

Comment: Do one thing create a new project and move this class to the new one.

Comment: Did so - can't find said method... at least I know now that something is amiss with this specific class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Create a New Project move the old Classes to the New one and Check!

Comment: That's what I did, and now its working ... I don't know why - but it's working... thank you man :)

Comment: No need for sorry! happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

its giving methodexception error
so see to it that the method named listofnoobs() is  not missing. 
also clean your project and then rebuild it